# mysql count only for distinct values in joined query

Tags: mysql, count

WOW! That's a weird title, but I'm happy you're looking, cause I couldn't find another way to say it.

I have a table of people and a table of links to photos and videos. 
I join the people to the media, and of course a person can have more than one piece of media.

I am attempting to grab the first 30 people and all of their media in one query, but when I say LIMIT 0,30. Of course I'll only get the first 30 media files, which could be 10 people.

Before I make the query, I don't know how many media files each person is going to have. Is there a way I can say LIMIT DISTINCT(uid 0,30)????

or something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you use subqueries in your version of MySQL?

> ```
> select *
> from media m
> inner join
>      ( select uid
>      from users_tbl
>      limit 0,30) map
>   on map.uid = m.uid
> inner join users_tbl u
>   on u.uid = m.uid
> ```

Comment: this is the way to do it if you can use sub-queries.  Good answer AviewAnew.

Comment: thanks AvewAnew, still learning my inners and outers, and I figured it had to be something like that. 
Haven't got it working perfectly, but I'm on the right track thanks to you.

Comment: MySQL 4.1 has supported subqueries, in general release, since 2004-10-23.  That's over four years ago!

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, here's another query that should return the same result:

```
SELECT *
FROM media m INNER JOIN users_tbl u USING (uid)
WHERE u.uid IN (SELECT uid FROM users_tbl ORDER BY uid LIMIT 0,30);
```

Note that when you use `LIMIT`, you should always use an `ORDER BY`.  Otherwise there is no guarantee *which* thirty users you'll get.