# indexes in mysql SELECT AS or using Views

Tags: mysql, indexing, derived-table

I'm in over my head with a big mysql query (mysql 5.0), and i'm hoping somebody here can help.

Earlier I asked how to get distinct values from a joined query
[mysql count only for distinct values in joined query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508707/mysql-count-only-for-distinct-values-in-joined-query)

The response I got worked (using a subquery with join as)

```
select *
from media m
inner join
     ( select uid
     from users_tbl
     limit 0,30) map
  on map.uid = m.uid
inner join users_tbl u
  on u.uid = m.uid
```

unfortunately, my query has grown more unruly, and though I have it running, joining into a derived table is taking too long because there is no indexes available to the derived query.

my query now looks like this

```
SELECT mdate.bid, mdate.fid, mdate.date, mdate.time, mdate.title, mdate.name, 
       mdate.address, mdate.rank, mdate.city, mdate.state, mdate.lat, mdate.`long`,
       ext.link, 
       ext.source, ext.pre, meta, mdate.img
FROM ext
RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT media.bid, 
         media.date, media.time, media.title, users.name, users.img, users.rank, media.address, 
         media.city, media.state, media.lat, media.`long`,
         GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tagname SEPARATOR ' | ') AS meta
  FROM media
  JOIN users ON media.bid = users.bid
  LEFT JOIN tags ON users.bid=tags.bid
  WHERE `long` BETWEEN -122.52224684058 AND -121.79760915942
    AND lat BETWEEN 37.07500915942 AND 37.79964684058
    AND date = '2009-02-23'
  GROUP BY media.bid, media.date
  ORDER BY media.date, users.rank DESC
  LIMIT 0, 30
) mdate ON (mdate.bid = ext.bid AND mdate.date = ext.date)
```

phew!

SO, as you can see, if I understand my problem correctly, i have two derivative tables without indexes (and i don't deny that I may have screwed up the Join statements somehow, but I kept messing with different types, is this ended up giving me the result I wanted).

What's the best way to create a query similar to this which will allow me to take advantage of the indexes?
Dare I say, I actually have one more table to add into the mix at a later date.

Currently, my query is taking .8 seconds to complete, but I'm sure if I could take advantage of the indexes, this could be significantly faster.

Comment: After looking into Quassnoi's recommendation of using SPACIAL INDEX, i realized their was an error in the index I had, and the response time has come down considerably (now 0.1 sec). 
However, EXPLAIN still points out that I am making a request of non-indexed columns.

Answer (score 1):

Starting fresh:

Question - why are you grouping by both media.bid and media.date? Can a bid have records for more than one date?

Here's a simpler version to try:

> ```
> SELECT 
>     mdate.bid,
>     mdate.fid,
>     mdate.date,
>     mdate.time,
>     mdate.title,
>     mdate.name, 
>     mdate.address,
>     mdate.rank,
>     mdate.city,
>     mdate.state,
>     mdate.lat,
>     mdate.`long`,
>     ext.link, 
>     ext.source,
>     ext.pre, 
>     meta,
>     mdate.img,
>     (   SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tagname SEPARATOR ' | ')
>         FROM tags 
>         WHERE ext.bid = tags.bid
>         ORDER BY tags.bid GROUP BY tags.bid
>     ) AS meta
>
> FROM 
>     ext
>
> LEFT JOIN
>     media ON ext.bid = media.bid AND ext.date = media.date
>
> JOIN
>     users ON ext.bid = users.bid
>
> WHERE 
>     `long` BETWEEN -122.52224684058 AND -121.79760915942
>     AND lat BETWEEN 37.07500915942 AND 37.79964684058
>     AND ext.date = '2009-02-23'
>     AND users.userid IN
>     (    
>         SELECT userid FROM users ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 30
>     )
>
> ORDER BY 
>     media.date, 
>     users.rank DESC
>     LIMIT 0, 30
> ```

Comment: Well, I'm not grouping on anything, I just formatted the query so that it's readable :)

Comment: thanks le dorfier, i've got things working pretty well now, but when I get past my current deadline, i'll try re-writing the query your way and see if I can get that working. It does look simpler.

Answer (score 1):

First, check for indices on `ext(bid, date)`, `users(bid)` and `tags(bid)`, you should really have them.

It seems, though, that it's `LONG` and `LAT` that cause you most problems. You should try keeping your `LONG` and `LAT` as a `(coordinate` [`POINT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-spatial-datatypes.html)`)`, create a `SPATIAL INDEX` on this column and query like that:

```
WHERE MBRContains(@MySquare, coordinate)
```

If you can't change your schema for some reason, you can try creating additional indices that include `date` as a first field:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_date_long ON media (date, `long`)
CREATE INDEX ix_date_lat ON media (date, lat)
```

These indices will be more efficient for you query, as you use exact search on `date` combined with a ranged search on `axes`.

Comment: Though I don't deny the benefits of SPATIAL INDEX, for some reason I was unable to create one on my database (probably because i am storing   lat & long seperately. I'll have to look into that. 
However, in the process I realized that i had an error in my latlong index. Query time is now 0.1 sec.

Comment: If you want SPATIAL, you should keep you coordinates as a special type, GEOMETRY (POINT, in your case). And the fact that LAT/LONG index did help tells us you really want SPATIAL :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to compare your perforamnces against using a temp table for each selection, and joining those tables together.

create table #whatever
create table #whatever2

insert into #whatever select...
insert into #whatever2 select...

select from #whatever join #whatever 2

....

drop table #whatever
drop table #whatever2

If your system has enough memory to hold full tables this might work out much faster. It depends on how big your database is.